# Naming a point on highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I want to name a few points on my time data with irregular intervals. I am trying this as shown on [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NE8ZJ/6/) by appending as

```
     { [Date.UTC(1970,  9, 27), 0 ] , name: 'point 1'},
```

but it is not working, any inputs ? I also want to have color for those points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/WMFz9/)

You will have to pass data like:

```
data: [
                    {x:Date.UTC(1970, 11,  2), y:2,color:'red', name:'point 1'},
                    {x:Date.UTC(1970, 11,  3), y:3,color:'blue', name:'point 2'},
                    {x:Date.UTC(1970, 11,  4), y:4,color:'orange', name:'point 3'},
                    [Date.UTC(1970, 11,  2), 0.8 ],
                    [Date.UTC(1970, 11,  9), 0.6 ],
                    .......
                    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Change from:

```
 { [Date.UTC(1970,  9, 27), 0 ] , name: 'point 1'},
```

To:

```
 { x: Date.UTC(1970,  9, 27), y: 0, name: 'point 1'},
```